# Including always changing code into an active program

Tags: c#, include

Take the following function as an example:

```
void Changing(string var1, string var2, string var3)
{
}
```

I have code written in `.txt` files, and I want it to be dynamically loaded into that function. Potentially the code could be different every time the function is called. How could I do this?

1. Code is in text files on the disk
2. Code should be dynamically loaded without stopping execution of program
3. Code should be indistinguishable from code loaded from the beginning, should pretend as if it was always there.
4. Location of the file to execute is included in `var1`.

Comment: This smells like homework, or an elaborate way create an injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't 100% pretend it was there from the beginning; you're going to have to work around it.

If the code is in an external text file, you have a number of options:

- use `CSharpCodeProvider` to compile the code at runtime; you'd need to add extra fluff to make it a well-defined class (presumably implementing a common interface); then use reflection to create an instance of the type; *yeuch* - and beware you can't unload, etc.
- wait until .NET 5.0 and hope that the compiler-as-a-service stays
- use Mono, where compiler-as-a-service [already exists](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler)
- run the external file as (for example) a python script via IronPython (note that this changes the script language)

I'd look at the last option (IronPython) first... seems made for this job.

Answer (score 0):

You can give scripting languages like [Lua](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/articles/DotNetScripting.aspx) or [boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/) a try. I've not implemented these but have seen the similar stuff work in java.